# [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self];

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

```
[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self];
```

Is there a problem, conceptually, with executing this line of code?

Answer (score 6):

No. The object will be removed from the MOC when it's synchronized, not now.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured; that it's simply "marked" for deletion. I don't have much knowledge of NS internals, so I was just curious.